# pH of a solution from mixed solution

Tags: acid-base, ph

I am not a chemistry student. I have a problem with my preserved food. I am afraid that the pH is not below 4.6 for it to safe to eat. I want to check the pH of the food but it has small amount of liquid. So I took a sample of 6 mL of it and then adding 100 mL of water. I don't have distilled water so I measure the pH of my water and it has pH of 7.1. Now I combine them together and check for the pH with my pH meter and the result is the mixture has pH of 3.6.

From my research I found this formula and I reverse the step to find the pH.

1. Find $[H^+] = 10^{-pH}$
2. $[H^+]_{mix} = \frac{[H^+]_1 \cdot V_1 + [H^+]_2 \cdot V_2}{V_1 + V_2}$ where the volume is in Liters
3. $pH_{mix} = -\log{[H^+]_{mix}}$

From there I solve for $[H^+]_2$ which I defined as for the fermented liquid. From my calculation I get that the $pH_2 = 2.35$.

Am I correct? Or is this formula wrong?
My formula is based from [here](https://www.chemteam.info/AcidBase/Calc-new-pH-given-pH-of-two-mixed-solutions.html)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Measuring pH of diluted solution can generally provide just rough estimation of possible pH range of the original solution.

---

You have based your mathematical analysis on the false premise of conservation of $\ce{H+}$ ion amount.

It is not like for other ions like $\ce{Na+}$ or $\mathrm{Cl-}$. Food frequently contains (natural, formed or added) weak acids (citric, acetic, tartaric, maleic or others) and their respective salts. With solution dilution or mixing, further $\ce{H+}$ can be formed by acid dissociation or the opposite, consumed by recombination, to keep respective chemical equilibrium.

Therefore, $\mathrm{pH}$ calculations are not that easy like for strong acids like $\ce{HCl}$. Generally, if there is a solution of known $\mathrm{pH}$ and if you dilute it in some ratio, there is no way to tell the final $\mathrm{pH}$, unless you know the solution composition or unless you measure the pH. E.g. if you diluted vinegar 10 times, $\mathrm{pH}$ would not increase by 1 like it would for $\ce{HCl}$, but just about by 0.5. If there was also a salt of the acetic acid present, it would increase much less, being a pH buffer.

*So, if some solution has $\mathrm{pH}=3.0$ and if you dilute it 10 times by distilled/deionized water, $\mathrm{pH}$ of the diluted solution can be in the range $3.0 - 4.0$.*

Additionally, tap water can also affect the resulting $\mathrm{pH}$, e.g. due dissolved carbon dioxide and/or bicarbonate.